# What's the difference between replying to someone else and forward in Inbox / Gmail?

Tags: gmail, inbox-by-gmail

This is about Google Inbox / Gmail.

When someone sends me a mail, and I wish to forward it to a third person, does it make any difference if, instead of forwarding it, I press reply, empty the To and CC fields, and then add the ID of the person I want to send it to?

In both cases:

- The mail I send is threaded in the same conversation.
- The recipient of my mail can't reply to the others in the thread (only to me).
- The sender or people CC'ed in the original discussion don't know that I've shared the information with a third person.

So, it looks like there's no difference between reply and forward. Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there really isn't much difference. The main feature of "reply" is that it auto-populates the "to:" field (and sometimes the "cc:" field, if you've chosen "reply all") for you.
(The `reply-to:` header is used, if it exists.)

There *may* be some differences in the headers that *some* email clients might pick up on, but Gmail (and, by extension, Inbox) doesn't. As you've noticed, it keeps both replies and forwards in the same conversation.

Comment: Hitting "Reply" will use the (hidden) "Reply-To" header (if present) to populate the "To" field - this might otherwise be unknown. The email client will often modify the subject header with a prefix, eg. "Re:" for reply and "Fwd:" for forward.

Comment: @w3dk The prefix is hidden in Inbox / Gmail unless you click Show Original. What difference does the Reply To header make? In both case, replies arrive in the same thread.

Comment: @VaddadiKartick The addressee may be using a different email client, which shows Re: or Fwd: to them. The Reply-To makes a difference when it is different from the From: field. This doesn't happen often with personal email, but is common with list emails.

Comment: You can also see the subject _prefix_ in Gmail if you click the "Show details" dropdown next to the addressee/to field (of course the subject/prefix can be edited when composing the email). The `reply-to` header can simply change who the "replied" email is addressed to - which could be different to who the email was sent from.

Answer (score 4):

The biggest difference between forward and reply is that forward includes the attachments.

of course if there are no attachments then there is very little difference.

Comment: Reply has an option to "Include original attachments". So the difference is only the default — forward includes the attachments (you have to remove them if you don't want them), while reply doesn't (you have to include them if you want them).

Answer (score -3):

Reply is an option to send new attachment to same address
Forward is an option to pass the same matter to other aaddress is the difference between both.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.